# I have installed pytorch, but I still meet bug below

Tags: python-2.7, pytorch

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/create_dictionary.py", line 7, in <module>
    from dataset import Dictionary
  File "/home/supermicro/xswork/xsvqa/dataset.py", line 6, in <module>
    import utils
  File "/home/supermicro/xswork/xsvqa/utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    import torch
ImportError: No module named torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/compute_softscore.py", line 10, in <module>
    from dataset import Dictionary
  File "/home/supermicro/xswork/xsvqa/dataset.py", line 6, in <module>
    import utils
  File "/home/supermicro/xswork/xsvqa/utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    import torch
ImportError: No module named torch
/home/supermicro/xswork/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/detection_features_converter.py", line 22, in <module>
    import utils
  File "/home/supermicro/xswork/xsvqa/utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    import torch
ImportError: No module named torch
```

Comment: Please format your code and provide more information (your system, how do you install python, how do you install pytorch, etc.).

Comment: Ubuntu14.04，cuda7.5，Python2.7.And,I install pytorch by run 'conda install pytorch torchvision cuda75 -c pytorch'

Comment: can you import pytorch in python console? What is the minimal code that is causing the error message above?

Comment: Thanks bug info'Traceback (most recent call last): File "tools/create_dictionary.py", line 7, in from dataset import Dictionary File "/home/supermicro/xswork/xsvqa/dataset.py", line 6, in import utils File "/home/supermicro/xswork/xsvqa/utils.py", line 7, in import torch ImportError: No module named torch '

Comment: What is the result of `conda list|grep pytorch`? Does it show that pytorch is installed on your system?

Comment: Yes,I can import pytorch in python console,

Comment: Then the error maybe caused by the bug in your code. Try to give a minimal code which reproduce the error.

Comment: output' (ENV)supermicro@supermicro04:~/xswork$ conda list|grep pytorch
cuda75                    1.0                  hf2493ae_0    pytorch
pytorch                   0.3.0           py27_cuda7.5.18_cudnn6.0.21hc114ab0_4  [cuda75]  pytorch
torchvision               0.2.0            py27hfb27419_1    pytorch
'

Comment: It is almost definitely a bug in your code or in your settings. I think it is not related to pytorch. You should try to find solutions which solve this kind of problems. Good luck

Comment: minimal code 'import torch
import torch.nn as nn'

Comment: something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119298/importerror-no-modules-named-but-modules-already-installed-in-dist-packages) may help you. Beside, format your post and comment in [markdown](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet) for better readability.

Comment: Any way,Thanks.I try to check my setting.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: No，I haven‘t by now.