# scipy "already installed" but "not found"

Tags: python, scipy

I am using python 3.9.y on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

When I call

```
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
```

on Spyder, I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
```

However, when I enter

```
conda install scipy
```

at the terminal,  I get

```
# All requested packages already installed.
```

Comment: A similar question has been asked. Might be helpful in this case: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119298/importerror-no-modules-named-but-modules-already-installed-in-dist-packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119298/importerror-no-modules-named-but-modules-already-installed-in-dist-packages)

Answer (score 1):

go to Tools > Preferences > Python Interpreter

[image]

and make sure you are using the python interpreter installed by conda and the right environment

you can find the active conda python path by entering this code in terminal :

```
conda env list
```

the active env has a star